Can't compile Linux-written Assembly code in Visual Studio with MASM
I have a bunch of previously working .s assembly files that I wrote several years ago in Linux, but turns out these files can't be compiled using Visual Studio MASM and online assemblers. I don't remember what compiler I used in Linux. Is it possible to either get compiler required for such files and use it in Visual Studio or fix files in some way to make them compatible with MASM? Here's example of assembly code I have:
_EXIT = 1
_PRINTF = 127

.SECT .TEXT
        MOV    CX, end - arr
        SHR    CX, 1
        PUSH   end - 2
        PUSH   CX
        
        CALL    PRINT_ARR
        ADD     SP, 4

        PUSH   0
        PUSH    _EXIT
        SYS
    
PRINT_ARR:
        PUSH    BP
        MOV     BP, SP
        
        MOV     SI, 6(BP)
        MOV     CX, 4(BP)
        

L1:     
        PUSH    (SI)
        PUSH    space
        PUSH    _PRINTF
        SYS
        ADD     SP, 6
        SUB     SI, 2
        LOOP L1
        
        PUSH    enter
        PUSH    _PRINTF
        SYS
        
        MOV     SP, BP
        POP     BP
        RET

.SECT .DATA
arr:    .WORD   1, 2, 3, 4, 5
end:    .BYTE   0
space:  .ASCIZ  "%d "
enter:  .ASCIZ  "\n"

.SECT .BSS

I tried changing file extension from .s to .asm and compiling it using Visual Studio 2022 with MASM support enabled, however IDE does not compile it and instead sends lots of errors. I also tried running this code in several online assemblers, but that didn't work either.

If nothing else, you need to figure out what SYS is supposed to do as that is not an x86 instruction. For the rest it is fairly trivial to adjust the syntax. In any case this is 16 bit code so even if you manage to assemble it it's unlikely what you really want.

I don't recognize the syntax; it's not Go assembler since MOV SI, 6(BP) is a load (of a function arg), but Go assembler has the destination on the right.  I don't know of another assembler that uses paren () instead of square brackets [] for addressing modes like AT&T does, but without decorating register names with %.  The AT&T version of that instruction would be mov 6(%bp), %si, and standard Intel syntax (like NASM or MASM) would be mov si, [bp + 6], with MASM also allowing mov si, 6[bp] I think.

Of course, it's easy to see what the intended meaning is, like push enter being NASM-like push imm16 of the address.  I'm guessing SYS is a macro, possibly pre-defined or defined on the command line, for an instruction like int something.  But it's not a DOS or BIOS interrupt since it's passing an arg and call number on the stack, rather than registers like DOS or BIOS calls would use.  And _PRINTF is a system call?  Makes me wonder if it's designed to run in an emulator/simulator with its own set of system calls like MARS for MIPS.

Okay, a bit research later and I found the assembler I used - Amsterdam Compiler Kit! I guess there's no way other than re-writing whole file to port it to MASM?

Right, many of the instructions would need to be edited, like every symbol address reference like push enter needs to be push OFFSET enter.  And I guess MOV    CX, OFFSET end - arr or OFFSET end - OFFSET arr?  Not sure how MASM does that.  The .byte and .asciz directives match the GNU assembler; MASM uses db and has no direct equivalent for .asciz so e.g. you'd do enter  db  "\n", 0 to append the zero terminator yourself.
